# Quote names in warnings

Tags: r, expression

This seems like an easy question, but I couldn't find the answer. I have a character vector containing names of arguments of a call. In a function, I would like to give a warning if some of those are wrong, and quote the names.

```
bad = c("a", "b", "c")
warning(paste("Variables", paste(bad, collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))
```

which gives:

```
Warning message:
Variables a, b, c are wrong
```

but I need:

```
Warning message:
Variables 'a', 'b', 'c' are wrong
```

I would like to achieve this without the use of external packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use ASCII apostrophe `\'`

```
warning(paste("Variables", paste0("\'", bad, "\'", collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))

# Warning message:
# Variables 'a', 'b', 'c' are wrong
```

Or a single quote by`sQuote`

```
warning(paste("Variables", paste(sQuote(bad), collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))

# Warning message:
# Variables ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’ are wrong
```

Or a double quote by`dQuote`

```
warning(paste("Variables", paste(dQuote(bad), collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))

# Warning message:
# Variables “a”, “b”, “c” are wrong
```

Comment: This is neat, but I wouldn't use left/right quotes in a warning. However, I wouldn't add quotes at all.

Comment: @Roland Thank you, edited my answer, however, the usage depends on the user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this approach:

```
warning("Variables ", paste0("'", bad, "'", collapse = ", "), " are wrong")
# Warning message:
# Variables 'a', 'b', 'c' are wrong
```

Alternative version for double quotation marks:

```
warning("Variables ", paste0("\"", bad, "\"", collapse = ", "), " are wrong")
# Warning message:
# Variables "a", "b", "c" are wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
bad = c("'a'", "'b'", "'c'")
warning(paste("Variables", paste(bad, collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))
```

if you want to save some typing you can write something like

```
quotify <- function(x) paste0("'", x, "'")

bad = quotify(c("a", "b", "c"))
warning(paste("Variables", paste(bad, collapse = ", "), "are wrong"))
```